# How to show a customer's order frequency over specific bands of time.

Tags: excel, t-sql, excel-formula

I have a list of E-mail addresses and order dates. I am trying to figure out how to display the number of customers that order every week, twice a month, once a month, once every 2 months, once every 3 months, once every 4 months, and once every 5 months or more.

What is the best way to accomplish this is? I have 400K records.

Comment: Do you have a table structure we can see as well as sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a pivot table that counts dates by e-address. With say 12 months of data Count of date = 6 is once every 2 months (on average!) =12 is once every month. That does not deal with an e-address that ordered 4 times in the last month of the year but I am not sure that is your requirement because if ordered on the last day of the year the frequency could be any of your options.